# angular button rating with collapse

Tags: angularjs, button, rating, ng-switch

The objective is to combine the rating provided here in example:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/rating
w/ the collapse here:
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse

Is it possible to make use the rating implementation and have each star binded to a unique collapse and message.(i.e. clicking 1 star collapses a message saying "you selected "{{rating}}" star!"

I was trying to use ng-switch at first, but any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this suit your needs ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/cGxCRDWb3OX5RzJjSwUV?p=preview

I just made the collapse condition equal to rating `ng-model` so the message only shows when there is a rating selected.

Comment: Not exactly. When clicking on one star, display message1. When clicking on two star, display message2. Doing this so that each star click is unique.

Comment: Check http://plnkr.co/edit/cGxCRDWb3OX5RzJjSwUV?p=preview again, I stored messages in an array